# Filtering out multiple records in dataset

Tags: php, sql, dataset

I'm working with a dataset coming back from a very complex view with multiple subselects and joins against several tables in a very large and convoluted database.

Each record has a structure like this:

`MainValue = XXTS10, qtyPlaceholder1, qtyPlaceholder2, qtyPlaceholder3..., actualQty = 3, qtyPlaceholderKey = 1, color = blue.`

`MainValue = XXTS10, qtyPlaceholder1, qtyPlaceholder2, qtyPlaceholder3..., actualQty = 10, qtyPlaceholderKey = 3, color = blue.`

`MainValue = XXTS10, qtyPlaceholder1, qtyPlaceholder2, qtyPlaceholder3..., actualQty = 9, qtyPlaceholderKey = 2, color = blue.`

So for each color and MainValue values, there are multiple records. I need to set the value of each qtyPlaceholder based on the actualQty where the qtyPlaceholderKey will tell me what value to put in each and derive only one record out of many so that the final single record looks like this:

`MainValue = XXTS10, qtyPlaceholder1 = 3, qtyPlaceholder2 = 9, qtyPlaceholder3 = 10, color = blue.`

I know I've done this hundreds of times over the years, but I'm just having mental block creating the proper looping structure and conditionals to create a single record out of many with the values mapped to the placeholders correctly. Trying to accomplish this in PHP, but it may be a good idea to reexamine the view and see if it can be adjusted, but I really don't want to go down that path if I can help it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in SQL using conditional aggregation.  Here is a `select` form of the query:

```
select MainValue,
       max(case when qtyPlaceholderKey = 1 then actualQty end) as qtyPlaceholder1,
       max(case when qtyPlaceholderKey = 2 then actualQty end) as qtyPlaceholder2,
       max(case when qtyPlaceholderKey = 3 then actualQty end) as qtyPlaceholder3,
       color
from complexview v
group by MainValue, color;
```

Comment: I like this. Will give it a whirl. Thanks!

Comment: This worked really well, and much faster than trying to parse through the dataset in PHP. One problem was that I also need header information from other columns and could not included those other columns from the view in the select with the grouping. SQL Server didn't like that, but since I only need one row of header data for each MainValue I just did a separate query to get that.

Thanks @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your array and create a new array indexed by

1. MainValue
2. color
3. qtyPlaceholderKey with a value of actualValue

Then 'flatten' the new array by looping through the new array and assigning key value pairs for MainValue, color and all qtyPlaceholderKeys and their corresponding actualValues.

---

```
$dbrows = array(
    array(
        'MainValue' => 'XXTS10',
        'actualQty' => 3,
        'qtyPlaceholderKey' => 1,
        'color' => 'blue',        
    ),
    array(
        'MainValue' => 'XXTS10',
        'actualQty' => 9,
        'qtyPlaceholderKey' => 2,
        'color' => 'blue',        
    ),
    array(
        'MainValue' => 'XXTS10',
        'actualQty' => 10,
        'qtyPlaceholderKey' => 3,
        'color' => 'blue',        
    ),    
);

$values = array();

foreach($dbrows as $r) {
    $values[$r['MainValue']][$r['color']][$r['qtyPlaceholderKey']] = $r['actualQty'];
}

$result = array();

foreach($values as $mainValue => $colorValues) {
    foreach($colorValues as $color => $qtyPlaceholderValues) {    
        $row = array('MainValue' => $mainValue, 'color' => $color);
        foreach($qtyPlaceholderValues as $qtyPlaceholderKey => $actualQty) {
            $row["qtyPlaceholderKey$qtyPlaceholderKey"] = $actualQty;
        }
        $result[] = $row;        
    }    
}

print_r($result);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/2g0zmq)

Comment: Thanks! I'm returning an array of objects, but that should work just the same with object notation instead. I will try both this and Gordon's case query.

Comment: @Malchesador made a slight change so the code could handle multiple colors per MainValue